# Changing default language of user interface on Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, language

I have installed my Windows 8 Pro with a ZH-TW version which is a traditional Chinese version but I have changed the display language to English on Languages. When i run lpksetup via run, it will not let will uninstall Korean because it said that Korean was my default language of user interface. How can I change it back to Chinese and Uninstall the Korean pack?

Comment: Did you change English to the default language and reboot? If bot it might still be locked until you do that. (Not tested on win8, but needed on win7).

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to change the language.

1)Open Run command and type the below

control.exe /name Microsoft.Language

This will help you to list of language which you want to change.

2)In control panel select "Advanced settings" and then select "Add a language" then add the language which you want to change.

Hope this helps !!!!